# Freeze after /dev/sdaX: clean

Tags: arch-linux, boot, freeze

I did a major update yesterday and after shutting down the computer and turning it on today, I constantly get jammed at:

`/dev/sdaX: clean 99999/999999 files, 999999/999999 blocks`

If I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> I get "watchdog did not shutdown" and reboots.

I cannot get into failsafe mode... I'm clueless! Any tips? Archlinux x64.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, i edited the boot line, removed the "quiet" keyword and found the nvidia drivers to be messing up the boot process. Installed 340xx and problem solved.

Comment: boot line in which file please?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen in the GRUB menu. Press "e" to edit, find the line that starts with "linux" and the last word you will see is "quiet". That's the one i removed.